# Filtering data in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm receiving data from the backend in the format shown in the `shifts` object below. I display the data in html divs on the frontend. I've also implemented a search feature as the one below to filter the data based on the `input` event.

When you run the code below as it is, you'll notice that the object `filteredData` contains the correct filtered data. My thinking was that I can now assign the filtered data to the shifts object i.e. `this.shifts=this.filteredData` but this does not work as expected. When i do this, the `shifts` object will only contain the filtered data based on the search input and when i remove everything from the search, the object does not reset to initial state. The interesting thing is, when i don't make this assignment: `this.shifts=this.filteredData` (as the snippet below), the logged `filteredData` object behaves as expected i.e. It only returns filtered data and on resetting the input I get all the data initially in the `shifts` object. Not sure why this happens.

My desired result is to assign the filtered data to the `shifts` object.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      search_input: '',
      shifts: {"John":[{"user_id":193,"shift_hours":0}],"Rose":[{"user_id":194,"shift_hours":0}]},
      filteredData: {},
  },
  
  methods: {
    searchInput() {
      let data = this.shifts
      let filter = {};

      for (var key in data) {
        if (key.toLowerCase().includes(this.search_input.toLowerCase())) {
          filter[key] = data[key];
        }
      }
      
      this.filteredData = filter;

      if (Object.keys(this.filteredData).length) {
        console.log(this.filteredData);
        //this.shifts = this.filteredData;        
        //console.log(this.shifts)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<input v-model="search_input" @input.prevent="searchInput" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) instead of a method [and a holder variable]

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    search_input: '',
    shifts: {
      "John": [{
        "user_id": 193,
        "shift_hours": 0
      }],
      "Rose": [{
        "user_id": 194,
        "shift_hours": 0
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData() {
      // return all if no filter
      if (this.search_input === '') {
        return this.shifts
      }

      // get just the keys which includes the filter
      const keys = Object.keys(this.shifts).filter(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(this.search_input))

      // use keys to reduce back into object
      return keys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc[curr] = this.shifts[curr]
        return acc
      }, {})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="search_input" type="text" />

  <pre>{{ filteredData }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While it does give the desired result, my use case needs the filtered data to be triggered by an input event which will update the shifts object to re-render my data based on the filtered data.